# How to compare numpy array element one by one taken consideration the position of the element?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to compare two numpy array one element by one element taking consider of the position. For example

```
[1, 2, 3]==[1, 2, 3]  -> True

[1, 2, 3]==[2, 1, 3]  -> False
```

I tried the following

```
    for index in range(list1.shape[0]):
        if list1[index] != list2[index]:
            return False
    return True
```

But I got the following error

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

However the following is not the correct usage of .any or .all

```
 numpy.any(numpy.array([1,2,3]), numpy.array([1,2,3]))


 numpy.all(numpy.array([1,2,3]), numpy.array([1,2,3]))
```

As it returns

```
 TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

I am very confused, can someone explain what I am doing wrong

Thanks

Comment: whats wrong  with `numpy.all(numpy.array([1,2,3])== numpy.array([1,2,3]))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass an array of booleans to `all`, for example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = np.array([2, 1, 3])
>>> a == b
array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> np.all(a==b) # also works with all for 1D arrays
False
```

---

Note that the built-in `all` is much faster than `np.all` for small arrays (and `np.array_equal` is slower still):

```
>>> timeit.timeit("all(a==b)", setup="import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3]); b = np.array([2, 1, 3])")
0.8798369040014222
>>> timeit.timeit("np.all(a==b)", setup="import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3]); b = np.array([2, 1, 3])")
9.980971871998918
>>> timeit.timeit("np.array_equal(a, b)", setup="import numpy as np; a = np.array([1, 2, 3]); b = np.array([2, 1, 3])")
13.838635700998566
```

but will not work correctly with multidimensional arrays:

```
>>> a = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
>>> b = a.copy()
>>> b[0, 0] = 42
>>> all(a==b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
>>> np.all(a==b)
False
```

---

For larger arrays, `np.all` is fastest:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("np.all(a==b)", setup="import numpy as np; a = np.arange(1000); b = a.copy(); b[999] = 0")
13.581198551000853
>>> timeit.timeit("all(a==b)", setup="import numpy as np; a = np.arange(1000); b = a.copy(); b[999] = 0")
30.610838356002205
>>> timeit.timeit("np.array_equal(a, b)", setup="import numpy as np; a = np.arange(1000); b = a.copy(); b[999] = 0")
17.95089965599982
```

Comment: You should probably use `np.all`, not the builtin `all`.

Comment: I assume there is a considerable difference, but I am on tablet so cannot test. I guess that the builtin one uses standard iteration protocol, while the np one uses a fast loop implemented in C.

Comment: A quick `timeit` test suggests `all` is an order of magnitude faster, which I find very surprising.

Comment: @jonrsharpe presumably that's for small a and b?

Comment: @AndyHayden yes, `len(a) == len(b) == 3`, per the OP's example. I have updated the answer with timings.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the difference is much more stark (for all vs np.all) for large arrays.

Comment: @jonrsharpe added some timing to mine, array_equal can be faster (as it can fail early). :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`array_equal`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html):

```
In [11]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

In [12]: b = np.array([2, 1, 3])

In [13]: np.array_equal(a, a)
Out[13]: True

In [14]: np.array_equal(a, b)
Out[14]: False
```

---

*This ought to be more efficient since you don't need to keep the temporary `a==b`...*

---

Note: a little about performance, for larger arrays you want to be using `np.all` rather than `all`. `array_equal` performs about the same *unless* the arrays differ early, then it is much faster as it can fail early:

```
In [21]: a = np.arange(100000)

In [22]: b = np.arange(100000)

In [23]: c = np.arange(1, 100000)

In [24]: %timeit np.array_equal(a, a)  # Note: I expected this to check is first, it doesn't
10000 loops, best of 3: 183 µs per loop

In [25]: %timeit np.array_equal(a, b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 189 µs per loop

In [26]: %timeit np.array_equal(a, c)
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.9 µs per loop

In [27]: %timeit np.all(a == b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 184 µs per loop

In [28]: %timeit np.all(a == c)
10000 loops, best of 3: 40.7 µs per loop

In [29]: %timeit all(a == b)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.69 ms per loop

In [30]: %timeit all(a == c) # ahem!
# TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```